# Pushing multiple files to smb share jcifs from local folder

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, smb, jcifs

How we can push multiple files from our local folder to smb share folder using java. I can do with my single file using smbFile and it is working. I am looking for pushing multiple file push to smb share.
Any reference links and sample code would be helpful.
Thanks.

EDIT, Reference of code :

SmbFile[] files = getSMBListOfFiles(sb, logger, domain, userName, password, sourcePath, sourcePattern);

```
if (files == null)
    return false;
output(sb, logger, "      Source file count: " + files.length);
String destFilename;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
InputStream fileInputStream;
byte[] buf;
int len;
for (SmbFile smbFile: files) {
    destFilename = destinationPath + smbFile.getName();
    output(sb, logger, "         copying " + smbFile.getName());
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destFilename);
        fileInputStream = smbFile.getInputStream();
        buf = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
        while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (SmbException e) {
        OutputHandler.output(sb, logger, "Exception during copyNetworkFilesToLocal stream to output, SMP issue: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

This works fine if i try to send one single file of anyformat. But if would like to send multiple file to smb share fromocal folder. For This i need thr help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a `SmbFile` object that is a root folder of your folder, that you want to upload to the shared folder. Then iterate through the `root.listFiles()` array.
Put the uploadable files in that folder.

I assume that, your `SmbFile[] files` array only contains one file if it's only uploading one file.

Or another possible solution is that, try to use [`SmbFileOutputStream`](https://javadoc.io/static/eu.agno3.jcifs/jcifs-ng/2.0.3/jcifs/smb/SmbFileOutputStream.html) and [`SmbFileInputStream`](https://javadoc.io/static/eu.agno3.jcifs/jcifs-ng/1.5.2/jcifs/smb/SmbFileInputStream.html) instead of `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using jcifs-library (which is quite outdated), so firstly I would recommend you to switch library. I switched to SMBJ and here is how I'm uploading file:

```
private static void upload(File source, DiskShare diskShare, String destPath, boolean overwrite) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream is = new java.io.FileInputStream(source)) {
            if (destPath != null && is != null) {

                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/creating-and-opening-files
                Set<AccessMask> accessMask = new HashSet<>(EnumSet.of(
                        AccessMask.FILE_READ_DATA,
                        AccessMask.FILE_WRITE_DATA, AccessMask.DELETE));
                Set<SMB2ShareAccess> shareAccesses = new HashSet<>(
                        EnumSet.of(SMB2ShareAccess.FILE_SHARE_WRITE));
                Set<FileAttributes> createOptions = new HashSet<>(
                        EnumSet.of(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL));

                try (com.hierynomus.smbj.share.File file = diskShare
                        .openFile(destPath, accessMask, createOptions,
                                shareAccesses,
                                (overwrite
                                        ? SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OVERWRITE_IF
                                        : SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_CREATE),
                                EnumSet.noneOf(SMB2CreateOptions.class))) {

                    int bufferSize = 2048;
                    if (source.length() > 20971520l) {
                        bufferSize = 131072;
                    }
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    long fileOffset = 0;
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        fileOffset = diskShare.getFileInformation(destPath)
                                .getStandardInformation().getEndOfFile();
                        file.write(buffer, fileOffset, 0, length);
                    }
                    file.flush();
                    file.close();
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Of course takes a little effort on connecting the SMB-server and authenticating before this, but that's another case...